# R - Histogram combining 2 continuous variables from the same observations

Tags: r, dataframe

So, im working on a project with digital XRay analysis. At the moment im trying to compare 2 different output continuous values for each XRay, both between 0-100.
So the database looks like:

```
n  result1   result2
1     24.3     15.2
2     45.7     89.7 ....
```

I would like to try to create a graph with y-axis beeing frequency count and x-axis the output result for both of them, but with different colors

Ive compared them with the ggplot but there was no obvious correlation between the two. So i wanted to try to visualise frequency of the outputs for data survey only

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, jose_bampi! The question is missing a bit of information we need to really be able to help you. Most questions on SO (and in the R tag especially) benefit a lot from being _reproducible_, including sample code you've tried, its results (and why it's wrong), and enough (not too much) sample data to demonstrate the issue, and in a format that is easily used (`dput(x)` is the most robust). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on `dput` and other techniques. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this ok?
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
xray <- tibble(
  n = 1:100,
  results1 = rnorm(100),
  results2 = rnorm(100)
)

# In order to plot the both, we need to pivot_longer the data

xray |> pivot_longer(-n) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = name))+geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Yes!!!!! Thats exactly it. Thank u very much, i could replicate it here.